# Best Software to Control and Manage SAN Storage?

Tags: replication, storage-area-network, disaster-recovery

We are going to buy A New San Storage for design our disastry site, Maybe HP SAN Storage, we are looking the best soltion for managing our SANs and creating replication between these two SANs? each SAN is resides in one of our building that is too far from each other.

which software do you recommend to managing our two SANs in two different site? the size of our SAN in 40TB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAN Storage software is generally vendor specific.  If you purchase a Lefthand SAN from HP, then you will use the software that comes with the SAN.  The same is true for other vendors.  HP/Leftand SANs have the ability to replicate from one SAN to another.  EMC (as well as other vendors) can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

sanbolic is very good software thats not SAN vendor specific